# Why do multiple connections from the same sqlalchemy engine produce different info?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, temp-tables

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3, and SQLAlchemy 1.0.11

I have code that looks like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://me@myhost/mydb')
conn = engine.connect()

metadata = sa.MetaData()

# Real table has more columns
mytable = sa.Table(
    'my_temp_table', metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('something', sa.String(200)),
    prefixes=['TEMPORARY'],
)

metadata.create_all(engine)

pg_conn = engine.raw_connection()
with pg_conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.copy_expert('''COPY my_temp_table (id, something)
                          FROM STDIN WITH CSV''',
                       open('somecsvfile', 'r'))
```

Now this works just fine - `cursor.rowcount` reports the expected number of rows inserted. I can even run `cursor.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM my_temp_table'); print(cursor.fetchone())` and it will display the same #. The problem is when I try to run a query from SQLAlchemy's connection, e.g

```
    result = conn.execute(sa.text('SELECT count(*) FROM my_temp_table'))
```

It doesn't matter where I put that. I've tried several places:

- inside the with block
- outside the with block
- after a `cursor.close()`
- after a `pg_conn.close()`

Nothing seems to work - no matter where I run the query from, it barfs with:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "my_temp_table" does not exist
```

The funny thing is that if I wrap that code in a `try/except` then I can do `cursor.execute(...)` in the except block successfully.

Actually, now that I'm writing this out, it appears that using the sqlalchemy connection *anywhere* fails to see that those tables exists.

So what gives? Why doesn't my SQLAlchemy connection see these tables, but the postgres (`engine.raw_connection()`) does?

### Edit:

To further the mystery - if I create the the connection *after* the `metadata.create_all(engine)`, it works! Well, sort of.

I can select from the tables, but then when I get the `engine.raw_connection()` it fails on `.copy_expert` because it can't find the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to note is that temporary tables are only visible to the connection which created them.

The second is that an `Engine` doesn't encapsulate a single connection; it manages a [connection *pool*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html).

Finally, the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html) points out that operations performed directly on an `Engine` (`engine.execute("select ...")` in their example) will internally acquire and release their own connections.

With all of this in mind, it's clear what's going on in your example:

- `conn = engine.connect()` acquires Connection #1 from the pool.
- `metadata.create_all(engine)` implicitly acquires Connection #2 (as #1 is still "in use" from the engine's perspective), uses it to create the table, and releases it back to the pool.
- `pg_conn = engine.raw_connection()` acquires #2 again, so the `COPY` executed via this object can still see the table.
- `conn` is still using #1, and nothing you do via this object will be able to see your temp table.

In your second case:

- `metadata.create_all(engine)` implicitly acquires/uses/releases Connection #1.
- `conn = engine.connect()` acquires #1 and holds it.
- `pg_conn = engine.raw_connection()` acquires #2, and the `COPY` fails to find the temp table.

The moral of the story: if you're doing something which relies on the connection state, you'd better be sure which connection you're using. Running commands directly on the `engine` is fine for standalone operations, but for anything involving temp tables, you should acquire one connection and stick with it through every step (including the table creation, which I suggest you change to `metadata.create_all(conn)`).

Comment: Nice. I wasn't even aware that `.create_all(conn)` was a thing. Works like a charm, and likely with less magic ;)

Comment: @Wayne: `create_all()` will accept anything [`Connectable`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connectable). I'd imagine that this applies to most things which need a database connection.

Comment: interesting point of fact - I stumbled across this again with the exact same problem. Future me: You'll probably have forgotten by now, but you need to use `conn = engine.connect(); pg_conn = conn.connection` to get at the raw connection, so you can do `metadata.create_all(conn)` and then use the raw connection later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't answer the *why* but it it is how to accomplish what I want.

Rather than:

```
pg_conn = engine.raw_connection()

with pg_conn.cursor() as cursor:
```

Just replace it with:

```
with conn.connection.cursor() as cursor:
```

The SQLAlchemy connection object [exposes its underlying DBAPI connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.connection) via the `.connection` property. And whatever magic involved there does the right thing.